# Getting text box value with JSP

Tags: jsp

I am creating a shopping portal.  In this portal, I have a cart page that displays the item chosen with a text field for entering the quantity needed.  I have numbered them using a while loop in `cart.jsp`.  I am retrieving those vales in `bill.jsp`. I am getting the first value but the other values are also the same as the first, not what we have given.  Does anyone know what is going wrong?

cart.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
<title>Shopping cart</title>

<style type="text/css">
                       * { font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana }
</style>
<base href="%3C%=basePath%%3E">
<title>My JSP 'bill.jsp' starting page</title>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
<meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/add.png" onclick="document.location='index.jsp'" alt="** PLEASE DESCRIBE THIS IMAGE **"> <img src="images/remove.png" onclick="document.location='remove.jsp'" alt="** PLEASE DESCRIBE THIS IMAGE **"> <img src="images/cart.png" onclick="document.location='cart.jsp'" alt="** PLEASE DESCRIBE THIS IMAGE **">
<h2>The shopping cart</h2>
<![CDATA[
    int i = 1;
    java.util.Enumeration content = session.getAttributeNames();
    out.println("<form name=f1 action=bill.jsp>");
    out.println("<table>");
    while (content.hasMoreElements()) {
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println(i);
        out.println(content.nextElement());
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td> <input type=text name=i>");
        out.println("</td>");
        i++;
    }
    out.println("</table>");
]]>
<a href="index.jsp"></a>
<h3><a href="index.jsp"><strong>Continue Shopping</strong></a></h3>
<a href="remove.jsp"><strong>Remove items From Cart</strong></a>
<form><input type="submit" value="generate bill"></form>
```

bill.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> -->
<![CDATA[ 
    int i = 1;
    java.util.Enumeration content = session.getAttributeNames();
    out.println("<form name=f2>");
    out.println("<table>");
    while (content.hasMoreElements()) {
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println(i);
        out.println(content.nextElement());
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td>");
        String a = request.getParameter("i");
        out.println(a);
        out.println("</td>");
        i++;
    }
    out.println("</table>");
    out.println("</form>");
]]>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for ex if i choose three elemnts the cart will display nane of the three items with three text fields.. iam entering the value 4,,7,5 but in bill.jsp just getting 4,4,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
String a = request.getParameter("i");
```

to

```
String[] a = request.getParameterValues("i");
```